# GAC Problem: Keep getting old version

Tags: iis, web-config, gac

I've created a simple httpModule, registered it on GAC and added it to the global web.config.

I've made some changes to the module, updated the version and changed it also on the web.config.

What happens is that i keep getting the old version. I've restarted the computer, removed it from the GAC, deleted the consumer app .net temp files, but still the consumer app render the old html code from the httpModule.

Any thoughts on what the hell is happening?

Thanks,
Bruno Figueiredo
http://www.brunofigueiredo.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you have an older version lying around in your bin folder? Another alternative is that some other code is comipled against the older version. If all else fails you can use [bindingRedirect](http://nayyeri.net/blog/redirect-assembly-versions-using-bindingredirect-element/) to force your new version.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the GAC.

Simple, any dependencies you have should be binary deployed to avoid versioning issues.

I blogged on this before: http://www.tigraine.at/2008/10/13/handling-dependencies/

Comment: We use GAC because the html generated by the module must be added to every application hosted by the IIS.